# How to open .txt file that contains ansi color codes

Tags: python, telnet, ansi-escape

In my telnet server written in python, if i send a message to client socket like this:

```
socket.send("\033[32;1mHello!\033[0m")
```

then it is correctly colorized for the client.

But when i use a text file, for example, hello.txt with such content:

```
\033[32;1mHello!\033[0m
```

and send it like this:

```
f = io.open("files/hello.txt",'r')
message = f.read()
f.close()
socket.send(message)
```

then text is not colorized and appears like this:

```
\033[32;1mHello!\033[0m
```

How do i make it also colorized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The backslashes will be escaped when read from the file, so try:

```
socket.send(message.decode('string_escape'))
```

Have a look at the docs for further reference: https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings. This may not work in python3 though.

**Update:** Turns out for python3 you'd have to:

```
import codecs
socket.send(codecs.getdecoder('unicode_escape')(message)[0])
```